# typescript interface is giving typeerror

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

why does typescript throws error on

```
interface IEmailUpdateCode {
  userId: string;
  smsCode: string;
  newEmail: string;
}

const val1: IEmailUpdateCode = {
    userId:"293842",
    smsCode:"293480243",
    newEmail:"abc@gm.com"
}

const data1:{
    [key: string]: string | number;
} = val1;

//error: Type 'IEmailUpdateCode' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: string | number; }'
```

but no error when written like this

```
const val2:{
     userId: string;
  smsCode: string;
  newEmail: string;
} = {
    userId:"293842",
    smsCode:"293480243",
    newEmail:"abc@gm.com"
}

const data2:{
    [key: string]: string | number;
} = val2;
```

how can i make it work by using TS interfaces?

[here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIFEC2dgBsCqADgCZyQDCA9sSgN4CwAUMsgK4DO0qxAXMu2CigA5gG4mLdpnZUafAUJBiJyEBADuWHLnmCR4xgF8mTBJRADkANzi4AjHwzY8RUhWooAvMgbMWbTihuHgAiACYATgBmAA4AFjCQgBoVSWlZCFDIqLiYgAYwuKjk1NUNLTxQuAAjBAABYUwAOjNMEKZjRlNzSzc4B19-ZABtAGsIAE9dRWEAXWmRZAAfVVZMaugDQ2RvG3sDEy7GMwswa1swnkGhji5efj0lAzSZDwWnlTVNZx0Hma2dj5SrcgrxwtF4okUn4XhkstFcgUiiUYWVvtoqrUGs1Wu0jIcTr0yHBLtcWGNJu85lTlqt1psOoC9mEDowgA) is the TS playground link

Comment: not exactly what you asked for, but if you replace `interface` with `type` this will [work](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgogWwIYEsA2BVMATJwIDCA9ttALxQDeAsAFBRQCuAzhAE4zYBcUzwbKAHYBzANx0GzBM2KkefASPH0ogiAHdEqNPP5CxdAL506AYyKC+UAG5I0ARh7xk6LLnyzyVCQyasO3ABEAEwAnADMABwALMGBADQ+ktKeXCER0ZEADMHR4QlJqhpa6GlIAEamAALCCAB05giBRia05pbAUO5IjjQqDADaANYQILqKwgC64-pQAD6qjAjl7MqGUBS2DsqtZhZWW8Fcfb4MLOycM0o+UjIkEFcGKmqaLjq8ete06xQnvucBNJhKKxAr9Xgpe5AjLZXL5RLgl4lHSBCrVWoNIhNFq0PYdLp4JBHP6DEZjD4TaYU2YLQRLFZsNYbGx2YI7WhAA)

Answer (score 0):

There is a subtle difference between type and interface in TypeScript. This GitHub issue explains it well: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300#issuecomment-332366024

TL;DR: this code will work:

```
type IEmailUpdateCode = {
  userId: string;
  smsCode: string;
  newEmail: string;  
}

const val1: IEmailUpdateCode = {
    userId:"293842",
    smsCode:"293480243",
    newEmail:"abc@gm.com"
}

const data1:{
    [key: string]: string | number;
} = val1;
```

Comment: is there any way, I would declare a interface then convert it somehow to type and then use it??

Comment: Yes, there is a way: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIFEC2dgBsCqADgCZyQDCA9sRAPrIDeAsAFDLvICuAztKsQC5k3MFFABzANysOwzNyo0hIsSCkyOICAHcsOXMtETpLAL6tWYAJ6EUVEADdoYACqUXNiAB4XAPgC8zGwcANoACsigyADWEFaUMMguALoCLuHJrOYs1rZoenhEpBTUKP7I9k5Qru6eXhjYhSRkEIp0vhYsCJQgIsgOcLgAjEIN+kUtbcjlQbI8fILIAEQATACcAMwAHAAsK0sANBrs3PJtQqubO1sADCs7G4fHyFq6jQbLcABGCAAC4pgAHTdTBLLKdbq9MDIYpwEaMZ4hWJWQyqcSpYRGNTIAA+L04mC+0BMpmm-UGQxMnVYkL6A1wKyEsw48yg-FRxmepwUpQ5ahMsleBQ+Kk5ZjJzPYrPZy3W2z2T2CJzOvNlV1u90eRyVLx0wou3z+AOBlFB4JYNJ6fVhjIROqRcT56KduPxhOJWTJ9JWVJYQA